# make a three.js animation from an image with effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, three.js

This a code made in three.js so its like a gemoetry big cube made with small cube written in css,but i want to make that the source will be an image and that image will be the big structure made with small cube,i.e-if the image is google logo the thing will be google made with small cubes and with the three.js effects,but i can't figure out how to do it.

```
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            background:#fff;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            font-weight: bold;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="../build/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var container, stats;
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var geometry, group;
        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
        document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
        init();
        animate();
        function init() {
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.z = 500;
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xffffff, 1, 10000 );
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
            group = new THREE.Group();
            for ( var i = 0; i < 1000; i ++ ) {
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                mesh.position.x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                mesh.position.y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                mesh.position.z = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                mesh.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                mesh.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                mesh.updateMatrix();
                group.add( mesh );
            }
            scene.add( group );
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.sortObjects = false;
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            stats = new Stats();
            container.appendChild( stats.dom );
        //
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        }
        function onWindowResize() {
            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }
        function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) * 10;
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) * 10;
        }
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
            stats.update();
        }
        function render() {
            var time = Date.now() * 0.001;
            var rx = Math.sin( time * 0.7 ) * 0.5,
                ry = Math.sin( time * 0.3 ) * 0.5,
                rz = Math.sin( time * 0.2 ) * 0.5;
            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );
            group.rotation.x = rx;
            group.rotation.y = ry;
            group.rotation.z = rz;
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
        </script></body></html>
```

UPDATE : after doing some research i found Those little cubes are called voxels. I want to upload an image and programmatically create a 3D structure using voxels. I have to create a 3D object from a 2D image. The other thing is to use Javascript to read the data of an image such that can get the color and transparency information of each individual pixel. I can use a canvas to draw the image, and then access the individual pixels to get their colors, so that's one way to read that data. Maybe three.js has a built-in way to do that also.For the 3D object I guess you could just say that white in the image is transparent, and that it's going to have a depth of 5 voxels or whatever. It would still be a flat representation though, just stretched on the Z axis.Still don't know how to combine and make the thing